# Why do I get IO::EAGAINWaitReadable with HTTParty?

Tags: ruby, linux, httparty

Bugsnag reports that from time to time `IO::EAGAINWaitReadable` exception is raised in production.

```
IO::EAGAINWaitReadable: Resource temporarily unavailable - read would block
```

The exception is raised on HTTP request via HTTParty, ultimately leading to `net/protocol.rb:153:in read_nonblock` in Ruby 2.1.3.

Why do I get `IO::EAGAINWaitReadable`? Why are sometimes HTTP requests blocking? And why not let them block, what's the deal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IO::EAGAINWaitReadable: Resource temporarily unavailable - read would block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669667/ioeagainwaitreadable-resource-temporarily-unavailable-read-would-block)

Answer (score 0):

The most general way to handle `IO::EAGAINWaitReadable` is:

```
begin
   result = io.read_nonblock(maxlen)
rescue IO::EAGAINWaitReadable
   IO.select([io])
   retry
end
```

So can do it without selection a port, but better with a selection as it is shewn in the example. Also you can look at the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36551655/446267) on how to trap the `WaitReadable` additionally to the specified.