# IO::EAGAINWaitReadable: Resource temporarily unavailable - read would block

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I get the following error when I try to use the method "read_nonblock" from the "socket" library

```
IO::EAGAINWaitReadable: Resource temporarily unavailable - read would block
```

But when I try it through the IRB on the terminal it works fine

How can I make it read the buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I get the following error when I try to use the method "read_nonblock" from the "socket" library

It is expected behaviour when the data isn't ready in the buffer. Since the exception, `IO::EAGAINWaitReadable` is originated from ruby version `2.1.0`, in older version you must trap `IO::WaitReadable` with additional port selection and retry. So do as it was adviced in the [ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-i-read_nonblock):

```
begin
   result = io.read_nonblock(maxlen)
rescue IO::WaitReadable
   IO.select([io])
   retry
end
```

For newer version os ruby you should trap `IO::EAGAINWaitReadable` also, but just with retrial reading for a timeout or infinitely. I haven't found out the example in the docs, but remember that it was without port selection:

```
begin
   result = io.read_nonblock(maxlen)
rescue IO::EAGAINWaitReadable
   retry
end
```

However some my investigations lead to that it is also better to do port selection on `IO::EAGAINWaitReadable`, so you'll can get:

```
begin
   result = io.read_nonblock(maxlen)
rescue IO::WaitReadable, IO::EAGAINWaitReadable
   IO.select([io])
   retry
end
```

To support the code with both versions of exception, just declare the definition of `IO::EAGAINWaitReadable` in **lib/** core under `if`  clause:

```
if ! ::IO.const_defined?(:EAGAINWaitReadable)
   class ::IO::EAGAINWaitReadable; end
end
```

Comment: rescuing IO::WaitReadable should be enough to include IO::EAGAINWaitReadable?


irb(main):005:0> IO::EAGAINWaitReadable < IO::WaitReadable
=> true

Comment: @gerky seems it is true not at all (in some versions I saw EWaitReadable ignored)

Comment: hmm..the line I posted was from ruby 2.3.0 irb. Also saw this: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-i-read_nonblock, seems like it should be enough to just catch IO::WaitReadable?

Comment: @gerky may be it is for the specific version, or rubinius or jruby